# Clashing triggers - mutating table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, mutating-table

I have a problem with a mutating table in Oracle. I have two tables, `Customer` and `Person`. I must update `ChangeDate` in `Customer` during modification of a `Person` row, so I created a trigger. Unfortunately there is a trigger on `Customer` which updates `Person` in some cases and that is causing a mutating table problem. Fortunately I don't have to update `Customer.ChangeDate` when updating `Person` if this change was caused by a `Customer` change.

So here is my question: how can I recognize that the `Person` trigger was fired by the `Customer` trigger?

Comment: Do the 'some cases' where `customer` has to update `person` include the case where *only* the `changedate` is modified, as seems to be the case when `person` is updated directly? Might be helpful to post the code for both triggers and the structure of both tables.

Comment: Hi Alex, unfortunately until Monday I will not be able to paste code of the trigger, but I know that If only `changedate` is modified then `person` is not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm used `global temporary table` with clearing after commit:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  column1  NUMBER,
  column2  NUMBER
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Answer (score 4):

Mutating table errors almost always indicate a problem with the data model or related business processes.  The most common cause is denormalisation, that is where data in one table is duplicated in some fashion in another table.  That seems to be the case here - your CUSTOMER table is holding metadata about another table, PERSON.  Only it's compounded by the cascade of information in the other direction.

The proper way to resolve this situation is to sort out the data model.  Is CUSTOMER a sub-type of PERSON or is it the other way round?  Determine which is the parent and which is the child, and make sure that information only flows in one direction: probably from super-type to sub-type.  Although a better solution would be to remove the data propagation altogether.

There are workarounds but they involve packages and other contrivances to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

@APC is completely correct.

I'll compromise a bit by remembering the times that I was not able to negotiate a correction to the data model.  In such a case, you may want to use a variable inside a package for one trigger to signal the other.

You can also put WHEN conditions in the trigger execution clause.

Finally if you're feeling like a real hacker, you can interrogate the PL/SQL call stack and look for other triggers there.